# How do I perform a left outer join using SPSS commands?

Tags: spss

Can SPSS commands (e.g., MERGE FILES) be used to perform a left outer join between 2 SPSS datasets? Assume that the join field is not unique in either dataset.

Example:
Let the left Dataset1 contains 2 fields -  ClassNbr and Fact1 -  and these 4 records . . .

```
1 A
1 D
2 A
3 B
```

Let Dataset2 contains 2 fields -  ClassNbr and Fact2 -  and these 3 records . . .

```
1 XX
1 XY
3 ZZ
```

I want to join Dataset1 and Dataset2 on ClassNbr. The desired result is a 6 record dataset as follows:

```
1 A XX
1 A XY
1 D XX
1 D XY
2 A (NULL)
3 B ZZ
```

I would prefer a solution that uses SPSS commands (as opposed to SQL/Python/etc.).

Comment: old question, but I find the answers too complicated. Can't you use merge as "outer partial join"?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware you can not do this directly. One potential way to do the workaround is to "reshape" the data from long format to wide format (using `casestovars`), do the merge, and then reshape back into long format (using `varstocases`). Below is a use example (if any clarification is needed on the code just ask).

```
data list free / ClassNbr (F1) Fact1 (A1).
begin data
1 A
1 D
2 A
3 B
end data.
dataset name data1.

casestovars 
/id = ClassNbr.

data list free / ClassNbr (F1) Fact2 (A2).
begin data
1 XX
1 XY
3 ZZ
end data.
dataset name data2.

casestovars 
/id = ClassNbr.

match files file = 'data1'
/file = 'data2'
/by ClassNbr.
execute.

varstocases
/make Fact1 FROM Fact1.1 to Fact1.2
/null = KEEP.
varstocases
/make Fact2 FROM Fact2.1 to Fact2.2
/null = KEEP.
```

This creates some cases that you do not want, here I have just defined a set of commands to identify those cases and take them out (I'm sure this could be improved to be more efficient).

```
*now cleaning up the extra records.
compute flag = 0.
if ClassNbr = lag(ClassNbr) and Fact1 = lag(Fact1) and Fact2 = lag(Fact2) flag = 1.
select if flag = 0.
execute.
if Fact1 = " " and Fact2 = " " flag = 1.
select if flag = 0.
execute.
if ClassNbr = lag(ClassNbr) and Fact1 = lag(Fact1) and Fact2 = " " flag = 1.
select if flag = 0.
execute.
if ClassNbr = lag(ClassNbr) and Fact2 = lag(Fact2) and Fact1 = " " flag = 1.
select if flag = 0.
execute.
```

I'm sure it would be possible to make this more robust (probably making some custom python functions). But hopefully this helps get you started.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if you install the "STATS CARTPROD" extension bundle. With this extension you can create a cartesian product as an intermediate step to create an outer join.

Since SPSS 22 you can download it directly from the progam menu Extra->Extension Bundles->Install and Download extension bundles. You can also download and install it manualy from here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/files/app?lang=en#/file/d0afcd4e-6d5d-4779-84ef-2b68bc81b861
Note that you must have installed "Python Essentials for SPSS" in order to get it work.

```
*** create the example data.

DATA LIST FREE / classnbr1 (F1) fact1 (A1).
BEGIN DATA
1 A
1 D
2 A
3 B
END DATA.
DATASET NAME data1.

DATA LIST FREE / classnbr2 (F1) fact2 (A2).
BEGIN DATA
1 XX
1 XY
3 ZZ
END DATA.
DATASET NAME data2.
```

I ran into problems when using capital letters in variable names while using the "STATS CARTPROD" extension. It is also important that "classnbr" has different variable names in both datasets.

```
*** create cartesian product using the STATS CARTPROD extension.

DATASET ACTIVATE data1.

STATS CARTPROD INPUT2=data2
   VAR1=classnbr1 fact1 VAR2=classnbr2 fact2
/SAVE OUTFILE="C:\MY FOLDER\cardprod.sav" DSNAME = cart.
EXECUTE.

*** create an equi join.

SELECT IF classnbr1 = classnbr2.
EXECUTE.

DELETE VARIABLES classnbr2.
```

Now include the cases which have no match in data2.

```
*** create left outer join
* assuming both data sets are ordered by classnbr1 and fact1

ADD FILES 
   /FILE = cart
   /FILE = data1
   /BY classnbr1 fact1.
EXECUTE.
DATASET NAME outer_join.
DATASET ACTIVATE outer_join.

COMPUTE select=1.
IF (length(fact2)=0 AND classnbr1=LAG(classnbr1) AND fact1=LAG(fact1)) select=0.
EXECUTE.

SELECT IF select = 1.
EXECUTE.
DELETE VARIABLES select.
```

However you might get into some trouble when using very big data sets. In that case the cartesian product will be huge.

To alleviate this effect a bit, you can drop all the cases from the data sets wich don't have a corresponding match on the respective other data set, *before* producing the cartesian product.

This is, how it can be done:

```
*** create the example data.
*** (I added an additional case to the second data set, which will be deleted 
in the result, since it has no match in the first data set)

DATA LIST FREE / classnbr1 (F1) fact1 (A1).
BEGIN DATA
1 A
1 D
2 A
3 B
END DATA.
DATASET NAME data1.

DATA LIST FREE / classnbr2 (F1) fact2 (A2).
BEGIN DATA
1 XX
1 XY
3 ZZ
4 XY
END DATA.
DATASET NAME data2.


*** select cases who (don't) have a matching correspondent in the other dataset

** Create a list of unique key values of data set data2 
** (In this Example the key Value is classnbr2).

DATASET ACTIVATE data2.
DATASET COPY data2_keylist.
DATASET ACTIVATE data2_keylist.

* Assuming the data set is already sorted by the key value.
* Mark the first occurance of every key kalue in the data set.
COMPUTE list = 1.
IF classnbr2 = LAG(classnbr2) list = 0.
SELECT IF list=1.
EXECUTE.

* Delete all variables except the (now unique) key value

MATCH FILES
   /FILE *
   /KEEP classnbr2.
EXECUTE.

** Match the list of data2 key values to data1 in order to mark
** which cases of data1 have at least one correspondent case in data 2.
DATASET ACTIVATE data1.
MATCH FILES
   /FILE *
   /TABLE data2_keylist
      /RENAME classnbr2=classnbr1
      /IN data2
   /BY classnbr1.
EXECUTE.

** Remove cases from data1 who don't have a correspondent in data2
** and store them in another dataset, because we need to add them later.
DATASET COPY date1_nomatch.
SELECT IF data2=1.
EXECUTE.

DATASET ACTIVATE date1_nomatch.
SELECT IF data2=0.
EXECUTE.

** Now doing the same for the other data set.

** Create a list of unique key values of data set data1 
** (In this Example the key Value is classnbr1).

DATASET ACTIVATE data1.
DATASET COPY data1_keylist.
DATASET ACTIVATE data1_keylist.

* Assuming the data set is already sorted by the key value.
* Mark the first occurance of every key kalue in the data set.
COMPUTE list = 1.
IF classnbr1 = LAG(classnbr1) list = 0.
SELECT IF list=1.
EXECUTE.

* Delete all variables except the (now unique) key value

MATCH FILES
   /FILE *
   /KEEP classnbr1.
EXECUTE.

** Match the list of data2 key values to data1 in order to mark
** which cases of data1 have at least one correspondent case in data 2.
DATASET ACTIVATE data2.
MATCH FILES
   /FILE *
   /TABLE data1_keylist
      /RENAME classnbr1=classnbr2
      /IN data1
   /BY classnbr2.
EXECUTE.


** Remove cases from data1 who don't have a correspondent in data2.
SELECT IF data1=1.
EXECUTE.

*** create a cartesian product of the two reduced datasets.
DATASET ACTIVATE data1.

STATS CARTPROD INPUT2=data2
   VAR1=classnbr1 fact1 VAR2=classnbr2 fact2
/SAVE OUTFILE="C:\MY FOLDER\cardprod.sav" DSNAME = outer_join.
EXECUTE.

*** create an equi join.
SELECT IF classnbr1 = classnbr2.
EXECUTE.

DELETE VARIABLES classnbr2.


*** create left outer join by adding the cases from date1_nomatch.
DATASET ACTIVATE outer_join.
ADD FILES 
   /FILE = *
   /FILE = date1_nomatch
   /BY classnbr1 fact1
   /DROP data2.
EXECUTE.

* Some cleaning up.
DATASET CLOSE data1_keylist.
DATASET CLOSE date1_nomatch.
DATASET CLOSE data2_keylist.
```